# If an object is not mutated anymore, can it be safely shared across threads? (Scala/Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, concurrency

If an object is not mutated anymore, can it be safely shared across threads? Or in other words: are var (non-final) fields safely published if they are practically immutable?

A contrived example with pseudo (sorry) code:

```
class Root {
  var field1: Int = 0
  var field2: String = ""
  var field3: SomeOtherObject = null
  // many more fields here
}

class SomeOtherObject {
  var field1: String = ""
  var field2: YetAnotherObject = null
}

var root = new Root()
root.field1 = 123
root.field2 = "some string"
root.field3 = new SomeOtherObject()
root.field3.field1 = "data"
root.field3.field2 = new YetAnotherObject()

// ... So basically an object tree of arbitrary levels of nesting

// From here on out none of the fields will change

// now if other threads use the above data, e.g.

Future {
  println(root.field1)
}

new Thread() {
  override def run() = root.field3.field1 ++ "hello"
}.start()

// In the real project it will be a thread from a webserver getting passed the object tree root
```

I realise this is not very idiomatic Scala. Let's imagine I don't actually have access to the code creating the object tree.

As far as I know this code is not thread safe. None of the data is safely published. None of the fields are final (val) and there's no synchronisation primitive in sight (besides `Thread.start()` and whatever is inside `Future.apply`.

I'm not asking how to make it thread-safe. My question is: is it thread-safe to share mutable data if it won't ever change after passing the reference through which that data can be reached is shared? I don't believe the JMM/jsr133 guarantees this for non-final fields.

**However** I cannot make a test program that proves this code is broken and needs more synchronisation. Leading me to believe something in the JMM after Java5 added a stronger guarantee? I'm using Scala 2.12 on Java8.

I've found this [all fields are final](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/all-fields-are-final/) as well as [jep188](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/188), but those are only proposals. Can anyone point me to the rule/specification why above code seems to be safe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If an object is not mutated anymore, can it be safely shared across threads? Or in other words: are var (non-final) fields safely published if they are practically immutable?

No.

You need to create a happens-before relationship to guarantee that the writes to the fields happen before reads. This doesn't happen automatically.

It might *appear* to work because the particular JVM you run the code on is flushing the writes to main memory. However, it's not guaranteed. This is the pernicious thing about concurrency bugs: the apparent lack of a problem doesn't indicate correctness.

---

To make the discussion in comments a bit more permanent:

> Would it be different if all fields were assigned to in the constructor? (Still not final fields). Would a happens-before relationship be created if the root reference is held in an AtomicReference? As in, would that then apply to 'the whole object tree' if that makes sense?

- It certainly wouldn't help if they are assigned in the constructor: you only get the happens-before (assignment happens before end of constructor) if the fields are final.
- In terms of using `AtomicReference`, it depends on when you assign it. ["The memory effects for accesses and updates of atomics generally follow the rules for volatiles"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html), so you would get a happens-before if you set the `AtomicReference` after you've assigned the fields; but you don't get the happens-before if you set the fields after setting the `AtomicReference`.

Comment: Ok, that was what I was thinking. Would it be different if all fields were assigned to in the constructor? (Still not final fields). Would a happens-before relationship be created if the root reference is held in an AtomicReference? As in, would that then apply to 'the whole object tree' if that makes sense?

Comment: @Wtr it certainly wouldn't help if they are assigned in the ctor, you only get the HB if the fields are final.

Comment: @Wtr in terms of using `AtomicReference`, it depends on when you assign it. ["The memory effects for accesses and updates of atomics generally follow the rules for volatiles"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html), so you would get a happens-before if you set the AR after you've assigned the fields; but you don't get the HB if you set the fields after setting the AR.